# How to create filter for Hibernate Lucene Search

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, lucene, hibernate-search

i am working on Spring and Hibernate project and i am using Hibernate Lucene Search. it's searching fine but while displaying result it's shows like this (i.e if i search for title)

```
 [id: 10 | title:easylib, id: 11 | title:IBM, id: 12 | title:Wipro]
```

but what i wanted is it should show only 'Wipro', not it's id or something else

this is my code(in POJO class for title) :

```
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 150)
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

this is in my DAO Class

```
private void doIndex() throws InterruptedException {
            Session session = getSession();

            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
            fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

        }

       private List<CatalogueBase> searchTitle(String queryString) {
            Session session = getSession();
            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);       
            QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CatalogueBase.class).get();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("subTitle","publishedplace","title").matching(queryString).createQuery();   
            org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CatalogueBase.class);           
            List<CatalogueBase> contactList = fullTextQuery.list();
            return contactList;
        }

    @Override
    public List<CatalogueBase> getSearchDao(String search) throws InterruptedException {
        doIndex();
        List<CatalogueBase> result = searchTitle(search); 
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query code is not rendering this output you are "displaying". I think you might be simply invoking the *toString()* method on the resulting `List<CatalogueBase>`. You say you're getting the right results from the query, now just transform the CatalogueBase instances.

An alternative to loading CatalogueBase instances is to use projections:

```
org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fts.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CatalogueBase.class);
fullTextQuery.setProjection("title");
List contactList = fullTextQuery.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got Answer, my mistake was

Before:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("id: ").append(this.getId()).append(" | title:").append(this.getTitle());
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

After:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(this.getTitle());
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, if that's what you are after you should really use the Projection as I suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this annotation `@Field(store = Store.YES)` on your field and then use `fullTextQuery.setProjection("title");` then only it will work.